# C# Desktop application: Forms data to pdf file conversion

Tags: c#, pdf

I have textboxes in a c# form application. 
I would like to take text within these text boxes and create a text file . Following which I would like to convert that text file into a PDF

Comment: Search Google ... there are many. Searched for you ... check this one http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/convertexttopdf.aspx

Comment: edited the question to be more precise ..

Comment: Then you you write the text from textbox to a textfile either by using `streamwriter class` or `File class` and then the link I have mentioned in earlier comment gives an example of converting text file to pdf.

Comment: Welcome. Posted the same as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write the text from textbox to a textfile either by using `streamwriter class` or `File class` and then check the below link which gives an example of converting text file to pdf

[Convert a Text File to a PDF File](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/convertexttopdf.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of generating PDFs from .NET. Popular free libraries are [SharpPDF](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/), [ABCpdf](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-5.htm), [iTextSharp](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries/itextsharp), and [PDFsharp](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries/pdfsharp).